# CSS3 box-shadow rendering issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Box-shadow renders incorrectly in firefox (was observed on v49).

Css:

```
.block {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0084A3;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

It renders asymmetrically and depend on window height.
Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rypqfe1/). Try to resize the window vertically and see what is happening to box-shadow. It's easy to achieve something like this: 
[invalid box-shadow rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNs1c.png). You can see that top shadow is much wider than bottom one.

Chrome and Safari handles it well.

I would appreciate any helpful ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #0084A3;` it gives same output in both firefox and chrome browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `-moz-box-shadow:  0 0 0 1px #0084A3;` for Firefox;

Comment: `-moz-box-shadow` no longer supported by firefox.

Answer (score 0):

San is right but Just for more detail..

There is 2 type of shadow 
1. Inner ( inset )
2. Outer ( default )

so in css3, by default it is taking outer shadow if you are not specified inset property.

**inset**

If not specified (default), the shadow is assumed to be a drop shadow (as if the box were raised above the content).

The presence of the inset keyword changes the shadow to one inside the frame (as if the content was depressed inside the box). Inset shadows are drawn inside the border (even transparent ones), above the background, but below content.

check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) for more detail