# How do I make an outline of a circle in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, icons, frontend

How can I create an outline of a circle using CSS, just having the stroke of a circle while the inside of the circle is empty?

I tried border but it doesnt display in chrome just firefox.
I tried:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.15em #000;
```

which looks great on chrome, but **in firefox it looks uneven jagged**.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
This is for circles used for check/filling in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw circle in html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921792/how-to-draw-circle-in-html-page)

Comment: How about using a radio button `<input type="radio"></input>`? [Examples here](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)

Comment: If that dupe doesn't do it for you, here [a bunch more](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+circle).

Comment: This CSS line is working correctly on a circle using Chrome and FireFox. See [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MmgGew)

Comment: Okay... I now see the subtile issue. Hold on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 box-shadow rendering issue in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629927/css3-box-shadow-rendering-issue-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a FireFox issue...

A way around would be to show the `shadow` inside the circle, instead of outside.

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.15em #000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.circle {
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

It should work on chrome, especially doing it this way.

Comment: That isn't the issue. OP knows how to draw a circle.